# Question with rant about "downvote trolls" and saying something else very rude - rude/abusive flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, flags, offensive, disputed-flags

I flagged a question featuring this paragraph as "rude or abusive".
(NSFW content, hover or tap to view.)

> PS. The reason Stack is one of the worst places to get any help is become we have all these downvote trolls. Don't bother downvoting if you aren't even interested in leaving a comment as to why you downvoted. I'm not psychic, I can't guess what's in your head and then fix it, nor is it my fault that I work for people who put me in these predicaments. What I have to say to you downvote trolls is this: EAT A COCK. I'd never use this awful site to show anything professional anyway.

I didn't edit the question to remove the rant because, frankly, I didn't want to in any way engage with the OP.

Why would that flag be **disputed**?

I do appreciate the moderator removing the rant.

(The question wasn't deleted between my flag and the mod removing the rant. The only thing that happened in that time was someone commenting that it was unclear, and getting a rude response. I guess not linking to the question is causing more trouble than linking would, so for 10k+ SO users, [here's the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54627799/timeline).)

---

For context, this is the **complete** question (since closed and deleted):

> Title: **How do I locally convert a *.json to a *.java file?**
>
> Given that I have no web access from work and that I have no *.class file, how can I generate a *.java file from a *.json file? Can I do this with ObjectMapper if I have no *.class file?
>
> > PS. The reason Stack is one of the worst places to get any help is become we have all these downvote trolls. Don't bother downvoting if you aren't even interested in leaving a comment as to why you downvoted. I'm not psychic, I can't guess what's in your head and then fix it, nor is it my fault that I work for people who put me in these predicaments. What I have to say to you downvote trolls is this: EAT A COCK. I'd never use this awful site to show anything professional anyway.
>
> [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class)

Comment: @Bart - Hmmm, that makes sense, although in this case penalizing the OP seems like the Right Thing™. (OP uses inappropriate language in other posts as well, and opted to be rude to someone trying -- successfully, it seemed to me -- to answer the question above.)

Comment: Yeah, my gut feeling is with you, but I have no insight into any follow-up or "otherwise squeaky clean history" of the OP.

Comment: Might be prudent to edit out the "eat a cock" from the title before this slides into the Hot Meta Posts box shortly. Not that it personally bothers me but it's a little much for people to deal with as they're logging into SO while eating their breakfast.

Comment: @n8te - ***Very*** good point.

Comment: *"but it's a little much for people to deal with as they're logging into SO while eating their breakfast. "* - Well - given that most people have sugar for breakfast, they can use a little spice with it...

Comment: I also note that one contributor tried to engage the OP in a discussion about why the question was unclear. Not a good idea: it should be clear that the OP has no interest in being constructive, so why bother.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's related to [this rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54627799/3) (by a ♦ moderator, but that doesn't matter; any user could have done that).

[image]

Rollbacks [automatically clear spam & rude/abusive flags cast after the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18876/295232) (the rollbacks are supposed to 'fix' the problem in the post), marking them as disputed.

Comment: Gotcha. So there's a UI problem here somewhere (a minor one). The mod has to do actions in a particular order to avoid disputing the flag. Thanks!!

Comment: *(he he, I got to upvote the answer twice, my vote on it on MSE was migrated with the answer, then I was able to vote again here on MSO. I undid the second one though. No cheating. :-) )*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder iirc disputed flags don't carry the same weight as declined ones, so it's not really that bad if flags end up that way.

Comment: @TheWanderer - No, I was just really curious why a mod would do it -- and now I know, he probably didn't do it (intentionally), it's a (minor) workflow issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: we commonly mark such flags as disputed, when the community could just have used editing or a rollback to fix the problem. The post *as a whole* is not rude and abusive, just a section in it, so is *recoverable*. Please try to recover it first before involving moderators; if this devolves into a rollback war or a user re-editing the post then the situation warrants our intervention.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But do these events not go unpunished? Does the OP at least receive a warning when it happens?

Comment: @E_net4: moderators can and do contact users to warn them about rude behaviour, yes. There is no *automated* warning.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If we _do_ decide to flag the question, should we still edit out the R/A content? I'm asking because for spam, the advice is to flag as spam and **not** edit out the spam - so that moderators can immediately see what's going on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Frankly, I'm not going to edit and get the abuse that person is going to heap on me, on SO and (in some cases) elsewhere. Intentionally marking such a flag as "disputed" is, IMHO, just wrong. If you look at the OP's other posts and comments, it's clear they're exactly the kind of person best left to moderators.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder at which point a custom flag is most welcome.

Comment: @S.L.Barth spam is a different case. For posts that are recoverable, please do roll back, unless that’s already been done. For a pattern of comments and posts with this behaviour, a custom flag is very welcome.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Gotcha, will do. :-)

Comment: And.....the OP has been removed. Quelle shock.